# CancelDrop with KnockoutSortable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-sortable

I'm trying to get the cancelDrop option to work with the Knockout sortable binding.  Right now, just for debugging, I'm trying to cancel all moves.

This is my markup

```
<ol class="toc-child" 
     data-bind="sortable: {template: 'listTemplate', data:children, isEnabled: $root.allowEditing, beforeMove: beforeMove }"></ol>
```

and this is my beforeMove function

```
this.beforeMove = function(arg, b, c){
    //debugger;
    arg.cancelDrop = true;
};
```

When I un-comment the debugger statement, I can see the function hit, I can see the cancelDrop property get set, and I even see

```
if (arg.cancelDrop) {
    $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
    return;
}
```

execute as it should.  But the move stays.

What's especially odd is that the beforeMove function seems to get called after the moved item has been planted in its new spot.  Should I expect to see this get called before that point?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I had an old version of the binding.  The line

```
$(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
```

should be

```
$(arg.sourceParent === arg.targetParent ? this : ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
```

Which fixes it.